# How to export to KML from Spatialite command line

Tags: kml, spatialite, command-line

The Spatialite GUI can export a Geometry column to KML file. How would one go about doing that from the Spatialite command line? I am looking for an example code preferably - the .help doesn't mention it and the function list is a little confusing to me.

Comment: I would read this manual page https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html and try the ExportKML with the documented syntax `SELECT ExportKML( table Text , geo_column Text , filename Text ) ;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried it in Spatialite-GUI 4.3 but it returns "no such column 'output'" - referring to the name of my table that I specified as first argument. Even tried to replace that argument with output.geometry - with no luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it - use Spatialite 4.3

I tried Select ExportKML() from GUI, but doesn't seem to work.
However the command-line .dumpkml works fine. See .help in Spatialite 4.3 for syntax.

Comment: You must use proper SQL syntax and put quotes around strings. This does work for me `SELECT exportkml('test_table','GEOMETRY','c:\test\dump.kml');`